# NSCache Not Working Properly , Not Able To Load Images From Cache

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, caching, networking

Since NSCache Has Been changed to generic type NSCache Now then this is the piece of code I am executing 
however , the console is printing -" After Image To Cache" & Dispatch Main Queue CustomImageView but Image From Cache Executed is not showing up in there !! maybe its not getting stored in cache that I am creating ! Any helps ? would be appreciated

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
```

class CustomImageView: UIImageView
{
    var imageURLString : String?

```
func loadImageUsingURlString(urlString: String)
{
    imageURLString = urlString

    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    image = nil
    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject ) as? UIImage
    {
        self.image = imageFromCache
        print("Image From Cache Executed")
        return
    }



    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler:
    {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error ?? "loadImageUsingURlString | Class : Helpers -> CustomImageView")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
            print("After Image To Cache")


            if self.imageURLString == urlString
            {
                print("Dispatch Main Queue CustomImageView[![enter image description here][1]][1]")
                self.image = imageToCache

            }
            else
            {
                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
            }



        }

    }).resume()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

`let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()` why You are using `AnyObject` here instead of types You are using, `String` and `UIImage`. You have unnecessary casting in code.

Second think:

```
if self.imageURLString == urlString
            {
                print("Dispatch Main Queue CustomImageView[![enter image description here][1]][1]")
                self.image = imageToCache

            }
            else
            {
                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
            }
```

You are not caching image if url match. You should delete `else` and leave `imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)` to execute always after async call.

By the way, always use code that better developer has written and tested:)
Try this: [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: when I am not using else condition images are getting nil

Comment: Where You are getting nil? if `imageToCache` is nil that means that data was corrupted or async call failed.

Comment: after removing the else the "Image From Cache Executed" is printing and the images are not displaying

Comment: Because You have some crazy casting! Why You are not using `let imageCache = NSCache<String, UIImage>()`??

Comment: its throwing an error , String is not Convertible To AnyObject

Comment: Use `NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()` and just cast `String as NSString` it will never fail.

Comment: By the way if the image is not displayed, do You call this loading method from main thread?

Comment: yes , it does load the images main block is executed but after one scroll when I scroll back to up images are showing white only

Comment: You are using this image view in table view? You know that table view is creating many objects of this cells. If cache is inside your view it will newer work. It should be a part of controller or some middle layer of Your code. Every cell will have its own cache.

Answer (score 1):

I think `if self.imageURLString == urlString` condition is not required, could you please try below code it's perfectly working for me?

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString){
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```